# Как сделать animation для мобильного Safari рабочим?

Tags: css

Всем доброго дня! Может кто подсказать как можно было сделать свойство animation, transform и т.д. для мобильного браузера Safari рабочим??? Там же что-то типа -webkit- использовалось?? Или же надо чтобы при нажатии на ссылку срабатывал :hover на моб Safari. ПОдскажите как правильно делалось пожалуйста

```
#nav-collapse ul li a:hover {
border-bottom: 6px solid #9bbe7e;
transition: 0.3s;
}
```

Надо чтобы вот эти стили тоже работали на Safari мобильном.

Answer (score 0):

Применяйте свойство `transition: 0.3s;` не к `#nav-collapse ul li a:hover`, а к `#nav-collapse ul li a`.

Answer (score -1):

[Can i use](http://caniuse.com/#search=animation) говорит, что animation и transition работает во всех мобильных сафари. Вы наверное ожидаете другого поведения от :hover? На тачскринах, ховер срабатывает, когда вы нажимаете на кнопку и не перестает работать после того, как вы поднимаете палец. Постарайтесь разделить свои стили на мобильные и десктопные.